# List setting null values with the parallel stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have the following code

```
final String arr[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(arr).parallelStream()
                          .peek(s -> list1.add(s + s))
                          .map(s -> s + s)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

And I get this following result:

```
[null, AA, DD, null]
[AA, BB, CC, DD]
```

Why some of the elements are showing `null` in list1? 
I know I'm supposed to use `SynchronizedList` with `parallelStream`, but `null` values are surprising to me.
As soon as you add something to a list that slot should be set and next execution should have added another value to it.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Which java version are you using?

Comment: @Eran this would be very hard to reproduce and not from a single call either... it's very indeterministic anyway

Comment: @Eugene I tried multiple times. Sometimes I got 3 elements in the `list1` List and sometimes 4, but I never got `null` elements.

Comment: I ran your program and did not get any null, however got 3 elements sometimes

Comment: @Eran see updated answer

Comment: @wenzi I don't know what special settings you might have I always get few nulls.Have you seen the accepted answer?

Comment: @fastcodejava thanks I saw the answer, I have not run the code by Eugene yet, but ran your code many times again and did see one time with null value. Nothing special was configured, was using Java 8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ArrayList` is *not* a thread-safe collection, and you try to update it from numerous threads with `parallelStream`, what you see is the result of `resizing` the internal array of that `ArrayList` - that operation is not thread safe either, you first increase the array and *then* move elements to it : may be elements have not been moved and you try to access it.

To make it more explicit, when resizing happens a *new* array is created with an increased size - this new array if full of `null`s *only* after the copying happens.

It's really un-predictable what will happen, just don't rely on any of these.

**EDIT**

I can't post this as a comment, but here is some code proving that `null` can be seen:

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .takeWhile(i -> {
                String arr[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "R", "T" };
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                Arrays.stream(arr)
                        .parallel()
                        .peek(list::add)
                        .forEach(x -> {
                        });

                if (list.contains(null)) {
                    System.out.println("It took " + i + " steps to see a null");
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            })
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Seeing `null` values should unsurprising give the array is full of `null` values before it is set. +1

Comment: Note that in a sequential execution, there wouldn’t be a resize operation at all, as both, the OP’s four elements and your ten elements, are within `ArrayList`’s default capacity. The resize operations are already the product of race conditions. The likelihood of these race conditions raises with the number of elements, that’s why your example has a higher likelihood of `null` values, whereas the OP’s example is more likely to produce exceptions, if you run it often enough.

Comment: I doubt this has to do with resize - as Holger pointed out, all elements fit into the default capacity. I guess it's more likely a race condition between calculating the index using `size`, setting the element and incrementing `size` within the `add` method. Multiple `add` calls write to the same index, each increments `size`, leading to skipped indices that remain `null`.

Comment: With a slightly adjusted testcode (I'm using java 8, no `takeWhile` for me) I found that the most likely position for `null` to be observed is index 0 - this surprised me a little  (observed nulls in 10000 iterations that did contain nulls: Result: 
0=9789; 1=2528; 2=995; 3=519; 4=423; 5=366; 6=316; 7=256; 8=154; 9=1). Size of the list was never > 10 in my experiments. (I did this just out of curiosity - I know it is pointless to reason about the multithreading-behavior of non-threadsafe code).

Comment: @Hulk *Multiple add calls write to the same index, each increments size, leading to skipped indices that remain null* that's a great way to explain it! but either way it is very hard to reason *how* exactly this would break - the thing is, it will